# Login depending on role

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

How can I redirect a user from the login window to a specific page?
I am trying to make a site for students/teachers and I want students to have a specific homepage with specific options, and the teachers to have a different one. I have tried this code but it only sends me to one of the choices no matter what user i use. In the DB i made a column with Status. A user can be "Profesor(Teacher)" or Student.
What have i done wrong in my code?

```
  if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1) {
     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
     $sql="SELECT * from users WHERE Status = 'Student'";
     $query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
     if ($role=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
     {
     header("location: http://site/prob.php");
   }else{
     header("location: http://site/connectafterlogin.php");
   }
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }
```

}
?>

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: `if ($role=mysqli_fetch_array($query))` just assigns a value to $role, and then tests whether that operation was successful. Which will always be true, unless there's a crash it always succeeds. And also the SQL query will return at least one row if any of your users have a status of "Student". So very likely it always returns true. Are you trying to check the status of a specific student according to their username? You probably need an extra clause in the WHERE and a parameter for the user. Seems like maybe you need to take a tutorial regarding SQL and PHP to grasp the basics a bit better.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: I am totally newbie but I catch on the way,I think